# Jquery Globalize format of number and Google Chrome

Tags: jquery-globalization

This fiddle return the correct value of "5,5" in both IE and FF but in Chrome it returns "5.5"

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tvSH/

```
Globalize.culture("sv-SE");
alert(Globalize.format(5.5));
```

Is there a bug in the Globalize plugin?

**edit:**

This is strange, in Web.Config (MVC3) I have this

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

Which means that the client sets the culture, both chrome and FF reports sv-SE, so the Globalize  culture loaded is sv-SE like in the fiddle above.

But if i debug the code above on line 767 in Chrome

```
return culture.name.length ? value.toLocaleString() : value.toString();
```

value.toLocaleString() will return en-US format

This works, but its a hack..

```
//Fixes a bug in Globalize/Chrome where Globalize.format returns en-US format even with sv-SE
if($.browser.webkit == true) {
    Globalize.orgFormat = Globalize.format;
    Globalize.format = function(value, format) {
        if(format == null) {
            format = "N";
        }

        return this.orgFormat(value, format);
    };
}
```

Comment: format="N" differs from format=null because all numbers have 2 digits after the decimal separator even if they are 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome does indeed seem to handle value.toLocaleString() in a different way from firefox, however I believe this should be considered as a Globalize bug.

I have corrected this behaviour in my [Globalize fork](https://github.com/erethnor/globalize), which was as simple as removing that toLocaleString iirc.

Comment: Just as a note, my fix has less performance impact on slower browesers like IE7. IE has correct behavior with the tostring method and if you use the custom globalize code in a datatable it will be reallt slow with just over 30 items in the table